# Override specific default value in a list using values file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to template k8s deployment file with helm.

I have these default values:

```yml
celery:
  name: celery
  nodeType: onDemand
  workers:
    - name: general
      replicas: 1
      threads: 4
```

Trying to override it with values file, with no luck.
I tried:

```yml
celery:
  workers[0]:
    replicas: 770

celery:
  workers[1]:
    replicas: 770

celery:
  workers[general]:
    replicas: 770
```

I don't want to override the entire list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it finally by converting it to dict:

```
celery:
  name: celery
  nodeType: onDemand
  workers:
    general:
      replicas: 1
      threads: 4
```